# How can I determine the max frequency of the clock signal for a 3 bit ripple counter

Tags: flipflop, cmos, ripple-counter

[image]I can't figure out how to determine the max frequency at which a ripple counter functions properly.

Comment: You'll need a better definition of "properly" for a start.

Comment: So that it can count as it is supposed too

Comment: I also added the output of the ripple counter for two different frequencies.

Comment: Ripple counters have their flaws: [propagation delay in asynchronous counter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367154/propagation-delay-in-asynchronous-counter). It becomes more significant the faster you clock it. The point at which it becomes a problem depends what you're using it for.

Comment: Simple answer is the max clock frequency of the first flip-flop.

Comment: Can u explain why please?

Comment: Because the first flip-flop is the one that has to run the fastest. The second one only has to run at half the speed of the first, and the third at half the speed of the second, and so on.

Comment: A [SN54L78](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_tidataBookVol2_45945352/1985_The_TTL_Data_Book_Vol_2#page/n373/mode/2up) for example, has an \$f_{max}\$ of 2.5MHz guaranteed, 3MHz typical. The 54**H**78 is 25MHz, so very much depends on exact part chosen.

Comment: I'm using 74HC76

Comment: Then find it's fmax in a datasheet. :)

Comment: See the [M74HC76](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ST%20Microelectronics%20PDFS/M74HC76.pdf) data sheet. Worst case is 21MHz, best case is 63MHz.